# To be one of the presidential candidates in this/these election(s)

Tags: sentence-construction, collocations

I was wondering whether in the following context the bold sentence sounds correct to you grammatically  and semantically:

> The 2020 United States presidential election is scheduled for Tuesday, November 3, 2020. 
>   Donald Trump, the 45th and incumbent president, has launched a reelection campaign for the Republican primaries. Therefore, needless to say **he will be one of the presidential candidates in this/these election/elections.**

I need to make sure which one is the correct collocation?!

> a. in this election 
>   b. in these elections

Comment: Use of election or elections is subjective. You can refer to this question, should be able to answer your query perse. You can then use this/these accordingly. https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4632/when-should-i-use-elections-instead-of-election

Comment: @PrernaJain That is not accurate in the context of US elections.

Comment: @Lambie Why so? Election in simple terms means a way of choosing a candidate or their preferences. So, by literal means, I don't see  how US elections are different here, provided the word 'elections' is getting used. Correct me if I missed out on something.

Comment: @PrernaJain Please read my answer. a presidential election (singular); the elections (more than one person is elected to more than one office).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

presidential election = the election of a president.

- The Orange Man will be one of the **candidates for president in these elections** or **in this presidential election.**

US presidents are elected in voting that takes place every four years in November.

There are others who are also elected at this time: Congresspeople and senators.

**In that sense, they are elections. But, it is also a  presidential election.**

It depends on whether you wish to refer to **the election of the president** only or you are referring to the entire event that is considered in the plural as not just the president is elected in November elections.

- the presidential election or election for president, or if president is understood, you can just use election.
- the (November) elections, more than just the president.

[presidential election - singular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_presidential_election)

Comment: Thank you very much @Lambie; as per your statements and whereas "elections" refers to more than one nominee who has volunteered for the elections, I think I had to write: "The 2020 United States presidential election**s**" rather than simply "election." Do you confirm? On top of that, I didn't realize what was wrong with my sentence: "He will be one of the **presidential candidates in  these elections**"?

Comment: @A-friend He will be one of the **candidates in this presidential election**.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples are valid syntax, however my understanding (I'm not from the USA) is that the majority of people would regard this event as a single nation-wide election, which would mean that only `"in this election"` was semantically correct.